# @PathVariable String with dot notation property not working correctly

Tags: java, rest

I have a webservice that accepts `@PathVariable` String property containing dot notation. For e.g. `remote.output.location`, `remote.output.templocation`, etc.
For some reason, when I send above properties from browser, the webservice only interprets first two words - i.e. `remote.output` for both properties.

However, request parameters work fine. `/webservice/prop?key=remote.output.location`

Using `@PathVariable: /webservice/prop/remote.output.location` - this doesn't work

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/prop/{key}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getPropertyValue(ModelMap model, @PathVariable("key") String key ) {        
    log.info("getPropertyValue() /prop/key :"+key);         
    return config.getProperty(key);
}
```

Comment: Can you try `/webservice/prop/remote_output_location`, please? I'm not sure if dots are allowed in URLs, except to define the domain.